# What is the difference between PreSaveAction() and PreSaveItem() on SharePoint list forms?

Tags: custom-form

I am performing some custom validation on a custom list form using javascript. I had my code in "PreSaveAction()" and it was working. At some point it stopped working and I determined that the code was now calling "PreSaveItem()" instead.

My fix is to simply rename my function, but since I don't know why exactly it started calling PreSaveItem I'd like to know what the difference is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In SharePoint `PreSaveItem` function is called when `onClick` event handler is fired for Save button in List Forms.

`PreSaveItem` function:

```
function PreSaveItem()
{   
   if ("function"==typeof(PreSaveAction))
   {
      return PreSaveAction();
   }
   return true;
}
```

`PreSaveAction` function from another hand,  allows to override behavior for a Save button. It is commonly used for client side validation, for example:

```
function PreSaveAction() {   
   return ifValidSSN();
}
```

Comment: To add to your answer, PreSaveItem is defined in form.js and automatically included. PreSaveAction only exists if it is defined by the user.

Answer (score 7):

I just want to add one thing, you should not override PreSaveItem - this is a SharePoint built in function.
Instead, like mentioned above - override/create PreSaveAction.

But: be sure to remember you may not be the only one doing so.

So, the correct way to do it is this, which will call other overrides if existed before your code:

```
__OriginalPreSaveAction = null;
function MyPreSaveAction (){
var amIValid = true;//do your thing
var areOtherValid = typeof(__OriginalPreSaveAction) === "function" ? __OriginalPreSaveAction():true;

return amIValid && areOtherValid;
}

function RegisterMyPreSaveAction(){
__OriginalPreSaveAction = PreSaveAction;
PreSaveAction = MyPreSaveAction;
}
```

and to register, simply call

```
RegisterMyPreSaveAction();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is very good [blog article](http://hannanazam.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-apps-custom-validation.html), about the difference of `PreSaveItem` and `PreSaveAction`.

Quote:

> The function "PreSaveItem" is simply checking if a function with name
>   "PreSaveAction" exists or not and if it exists invoke it and return
>   its returned value (true/false) or return "true" by default if no
>   functions exists with this name.

PreSaveItem call is made in the `onclick` handler or the button and is as follows:

```
if (!PreSaveItem())
          return false;
if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ1'))
          return false;
```

The PreSaveItem function is declared is like this:

```
function PreSaveItem(){
    a:;
    return "function" == typeof PreSaveAction?PreSaveAction():true
}
```

It seems that `PreSaveAction` is much better and cleaner approach to make some actions before submit. But you have to **check and make sure** if SharePoint default `PreSaveItem` function is loaded correctly.