# Showing error of 'PreSaveItem is not defined' when trying to save item in any list on restored site

Tags: 2010, javascript, backup, restore

We took a backup of production site and restored it on our development server. The site has been developed on OOB or SharePoint Designer with no custom development on it. The restoration process went fine with no errors thrown.

But when we try to save item in any list the console throws error that:

```
PreSaveItem is not defined
```

I checked and found that there is not custom JavaScript code in either `PreSaveItem` or `PreSaveAction` written. The items are getting saved on production site completely fine.

It seems that the library where `PreSaveItem` function is defined is absent. But I am not able to pinpoint anything over here. Any possible leads on how should this problem be approached? Anything we can make sure to verify that the restoration process was error free?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between PreSaveAction() and PreSaveItem() on SharePoint list forms?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/what-is-the-difference-between-presaveaction-and-presaveitem-on-sharepoint-l)

Comment: @DannyEngelman: Updated my question to detail out how the question is different. Any ideas what could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

*I can't test for SP2010*

PreSaveItem is declared in `forms.js` and available on all EditForm.aspx and NewForm.aspx pages by default. It is loaded with a script tag in the aspx file head; immediatly after `clientforms.js`

Compare the header of a NewForm.aspx from a newly created List with your aspx file

It is not a very special function:

```
function PreSaveItem() {
 a: ;return "function" == typeof PreSaveAction ? PreSaveAction() : true
}
```

I can only presume your aspx files are modified